# Bike chain worn to 1% according to indicator tool

Tags: chain

My bike chain is worn to the 1% gauge on my indicator but only on certain links.  I could check a different link and it won't fit at all. However it would drop right through on certain links.

Should I be looking at replacing the chain and rear cassette?

Comment: How many places, percentage wise, does it "drop right through"?

Comment: Uneven wear is a good enough reason to replace the chain. And odds are if the chain is worn so is the cassette.

Comment: If you have a master link make sure you are not measuring over it. Sometimes they can add a tiny bit of extra length to the chain so that when the measuring tool spans a master link it can give inaccurate results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the chain at such condition (if there are 3 or more places or if there are multiple links).
About the cassette it's another question, and if you can't decide yourself, it should be checked in LBS probably.